# Unintuitive behaviour of Poltergeist's `page.status_code`

Tags: ruby, poltergeist

We have a feature:

```
@smoke @acceptance
Scenario: Home page is available
  When I visit the home page url
  Then I expect no error code
```

With the final line implemented as:

```
Then(/^I expect no error code$/) do
  expect(page.status_code).to eq 200
end
```

This sometimes fails. When debugging we've found the following:

- the page itself always responds with `200`
- however, one resource within the page sometimes responds with `204`
  (which causes the test to fail)

This suggests that `page.status_code` does not equal the status code of the actual URL requested, but could be set to the status code of any (or presumably the last?) of the resources requested by the page.

Is this the correct explanation, and is it the expected behaviour of `page.status_code`?

Notes:

- I realise that `204` could be construed as success, but this is not the
  focus of this issue

Comment: Also raised in GH https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/776

Answer (score 0):

status_code returns the result of the last request that triggered the phantomjs onLoadStarted callback - this should be the page, or potentially ajax requests initiated by the page -- it should not be assets being loaded directly as resources on the page (img, javascripts, css, etc).  If it is a dependent asset then phantomjs has an issue and should be reported with reproducible example on that project.  What type of request is reporting with a 204 response?  If it's an ajax request then it is as expected -  if not then its a bug in phantomjs.  Note: checking response codes when using Capybara really is an anti-pattern, and you should generally stick to testing visible changes on the page.